# How the Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke work in windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

i got experience with windows phone 8 and i am using WCF data services, i am able to update my record successfully with following code :

```
public void UpdateJob1(EquipBooking equipBooking)
        {
            this._context.UpdateObject(equipBooking);
            this._context.BeginSaveChanges(OnChangesSaved, this._context);
        }

        private void OnChangesSaved(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            bool errorFound = false;
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                this._context = result.AsyncState as THA001_devEntities;

                try
                {
                    // Complete the save changes operation.
                    this._context.EndSaveChanges(result);
                }
                catch (DataServiceRequestException ex)
                {
                    errorFound = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Error, While Updating Record");
                }

                if (!errorFound)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Updated");
                }
            }
            );

        }
```

but i got problem while write same code in window store app, i am not able to update record , i got problem here : `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

can anyone guide me, or rewrite my code?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using this instead of the Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

```
CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
      {

      });
```

EDIT:

The whole method then being:

```
private async void OnChangesSaved(IAsyncResult result)
{
    bool errorFound = false;
    CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
      {
        this._context = result.AsyncState as THA001_devEntities;
        try
        {
            // Complete the save changes operation.
            this._context.EndSaveChanges(result);
        }
        catch (DataServiceRequestException ex)
        {
            errorFound = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Error, While Updating Record");
        }

        if (!errorFound)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Updated");
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: i guess, i dont know about it, can you rewrite my code ?please

Comment: @vb1 there, the method is rewritten.

Comment: i added one more answer, if it is same like yours, then i will mark your answer is final

Comment: I get: System.InvalidOperationException: No current Window object found to obtain a CoreDispatcher from. Or CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread() is simply null.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i re write, please approve the syntax

```
public void ModfityJobs(EquipBooking equipBooking)
        {
            try
            {
                this.IsDataLoaded = true;
                _context.BeginSaveChanges(ModfityJobsAsynchCallBack, equipBooking);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private void ModfityJobsAsynchCallBack(IAsyncResult synchresult)
        {
            try
            {
                dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                    {
                        _context.EndSaveChanges(synchresult);
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```